# Order by value in spark pair RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a spark pair RDD (key, count) as below

```
Array[(String, Int)] = Array((a,1), (b,2), (c,1), (d,3))
```

Using spark scala API how to get a new pair RDD which is sorted by value?

Required result: `Array((d,3), (b,2), (a,1), (c,1))`

Comment: Could be there repetitions in the values? In case not: swap the keys and values and sort by key, swap back.

Comment: Yes, values are repeated.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

This should work:

```
//Assuming the pair's second type has an Ordering, which is the case for Int
rdd.sortBy(_._2) // same as rdd.sortBy(pair => pair._2)
```

(Though you might want to take the key to account too when there are ties.)

Comment: Hi @GáborBakos, I created a map like this - `val b = a.map(x => (x(0), x) )` Here `b` is of the type  `org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Any, org.apache.spark.sql.Row)]` When I try `b.sortBy(_._2)` it does not work. Is there a discussion on how to use _

Comment: Hi @SumitKumarGhosh, this seems like a different question. I think you need to define an `Ordering` for your [`org.apache.spark.sql.Row`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.1/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Row) type, as it is not `Ordered`. If you create a new question please also add the error message too. The `_` is just a syntactic sugar for the following: `aVariable => aVariable`, so `_._2` could have been written like this too: `pair => pair._2`.

Comment: [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30469864/order-by-value-in-spark-pairrdd-from-key-value-where-the-value-is-from-spark-s)

Comment: For those who came to this post searching for a PySpark solution: `rdd.sortBy(lambda pair:pair[1])`

Comment: For descending order, use: `rdd.sortBy(_._2, false)`
reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41918826/how-to-order-my-tuple-of-spark-results-descending-order-using-value

Answer (score 9):

Sort by key and value in ascending and descending order

```
val textfile = sc.textFile("file:///home/hdfs/input.txt")
val words = textfile.flatMap(line => line.split(" "))
//Sort by value in descending order. For ascending order remove 'false' argument from sortBy
words.map( word => (word,1)).reduceByKey((a,b) => a+b).sortBy(_._2,false)
//for ascending order by value
words.map( word => (word,1)).reduceByKey((a,b) => a+b).sortBy(_._2)

//Sort by key in ascending order
words.map( word => (word,1)).reduceByKey((a,b) => a+b).sortByKey
//Sort by key in descending order
words.map( word => (word,1)).reduceByKey((a,b) => a+b).sortByKey(false)
```

This can be done in another way by applying sortByKey after swapping the key and value

```
//Sort By value by swapping key and value and then using sortByKey
val sortbyvalue = words.map( word => (word,1)).reduceByKey((a,b) => a+b)
val descendingSortByvalue = sortbyvalue.map(x => (x._2,x._1)).sortByKey(false)
descendingSortByvalue.toDF.show
descendingSortByvalue.foreach {n => {
val word=  n._1
val count = n._2
println(s"$word:$count")}}
```

Comment: Thanks Vijay Innamuri

Comment: In the latter case, shouldn't it go like that?
`val descendingSortByvalue = sortbyvalue.map(x => (x._2,x._1)).sortByKey(false)`