# Order by Value in Spark pairRDD from (Key,Value) where the value is from spark-sql

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have created a map like this -

```
val b = a.map(x => (x(0), x) )
```

Here b is of the type

```
org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Any, org.apache.spark.sql.Row)]
```

1. How can I sort the PairRDD within each key using a field from the value row?
2. After that I want to run a function which processes all the values for each Key in isolation in the previously sorted order. Is that possible? If yes can you please give an example.
3. Is there any consideration needed for Partitioning the Pair RDD?

Comment: The simple way would be to group by key then sort (locally) value iterables and then run you function on values. Ofc this is viable if there is not too many values for one key.

Answer (score 1):

Answering only your first question:

```
val indexToSelect: Int = ??? //points to sortable type (has Ordering or is Ordered)
sorted = rdd.sortBy(pair => pair._2(indexToSelect))
```

What this does, it just selects the second value in the pair (`pair._2`) and from that row it selects the appropriate value (`(indexToSelect)` or more verbosely: `.apply(indexToSelect)`).

Comment: As `Row` returns `Any`, you shall have to provide an implicit `Ordering[Any]` and a `ClassTag[Any]` explicitly too, probably by type casting the values: `sortBy(_._2(idx))(yourOrdering, yourClassTag)`.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Gábor Bakos. I had tried something like this - `b.foreach(println(_._2(2)))` but I got the error `missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1) => x$1._2(2))`

Comment: In that case try something like this: `b.foreach(println((pair: (Any, Row)) => row._2(2)))`

Comment: I looked at [link](https://gist.github.com/joshjdevl/b9af68b11398fd1823c4) for the `Ordering` & `ClassTag`. `ClassTag` will be `Any` as I understand but how do I get the `idx` field from `Any` in the `Ordering`

Comment: You have to cast for that task. If you know in advance the structure, you probably do not need `ClassTag`s, `isInstanceOf` might be sufficient.

Comment: Thanks Gábor. got the `Orfering` function by casting -
`def compare(a:Any, b:Any) = a.asInstanceOf[Record].Age compare b.asInstanceOf[Record].Age`

But I am not able to get the ClassTag correct. It is failing on it.
`b.sortBy(_._2(6))(SortOrdering, ??? )`

Comment: As for `ClassTag`, you are probably right and `ClassTag[Any]` is what you need, in case that is not working, `ClassTag[Object]`/`ClassTag[AnyRef]` might work better (I doubt anything is specialized, so probably there are no primitive types there).