# how to order my tuple of spark results descending order using value

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark

I am new to spark and scala. I need to order my result count tuple which is like (course, count) into descending order. I put like below

```
 val results = ratings.countByValue()
 val sortedResults = results.toSeq.sortBy(_._2)
```

But still its't working. In the above way it will sort the results by count with ascending order. But I need to have it in descending order. Can anybody please help me.

Results would be like below

```
(History, 12100),
(Music, 13200),
(Drama, 143000)
```

But I need to display it like below

```
(Drama, 143000),
(Music, 13200),
(History, 12100)
```

thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have almost done it! you need add additional parameter for descending order as [`RDD` `sortBy()` method](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.html#sortBy(scala.Function1,%20boolean,%20int,%20scala.math.Ordering,%20scala.reflect.ClassTag)) arrange elements in **ascending order by default**.

```
val results = ratings.countByValue()
val sortedRdd = results.sortBy(_._2, false)

//Just to display results from RDD
println(sortedRdd.collect().toList)
```

Comment: @Dilee it's much better if you do it how mrsrinivas put it ... that way you get to keep all the advantages of having a distributed collection etc :) My answer is totally missing this because I just concentrated on scala part of the question :)

Comment: this didn't work for me with newer Scala/Spark but it worked when I used  results.toSeq.sortBy(_._2).reverse

Answer (score 6):

You can use

```
.sortWith(_._2 >_._2)
```

most of the time calling toSeq is not good idea because driver needs to put this in memory and you might run out of memory in on larger data sets. I guess this is o.k. for intro to spark.

Comment: It works. Thanks. Could you please explain me what does it mean by (_._2 >_._2). Still I have a confusion on how does this work?

Comment: this sorts a collection by comparing the items with the function that you give to it. It's a shorter notation for [ (x, y) => x > y ] it's the same as _ > _ and you want to compare by the second element of a tuple and then you get _._2 >_._2 hope this helps you ;) - It also took me a while to get used to this scala magic :)

Answer (score -1):

For example, someRDD is a pair RDD and the value is comparable, you can do like this:
someRDD.sortBy(item=>(item._2, false))

note: do not forget the brackets after =>.