# How to Sorting results after run code in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I created some code lines of scala to count number of words in a text file (in Spark). The result such like this:

```
(further,,1)
(Hai,,2)
(excluded,1)
(V.,5)
```

I wonder that can I sort the result as follow:

```
(V.,5)
(Hai,,2)
(excluded,1)
(further,,1)
```

The code as showed bellow, thank you for your help!

```
val wordCounts = textFile.flatMap(line => line.split(" ")).map(word => (word, 1)).reduceByKey((a, b) => a + b)
    wordCounts.collect()
    wordCounts.saveAsTextFile("./WordCountTest")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to order my tuple of spark results descending order using value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41918826/how-to-order-my-tuple-of-spark-results-descending-order-using-value)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to sort your first dataset by the second field, you can use the following code:

```
val wordCounts = Seq(
    ("V.",5),  
    ("Hai",2),
    ("excluded",1),
    ("further",1)
)

val wcOrdered = wordCounts.sortBy(_._2).reverse
```

which yields the following result

```
wcOrdered: Seq[(String, Int)] = List((V.,5), (Hai,2), (further,1), (excluded,1))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but my data set is very large, I mean, I want my output will be sorted. What can I edit or add in my code?

Comment: I used the variable `wordCounts` to give you an example based in what you posted. if you need to order a dataset in other variable, you should use `val wcOrdered = datasetYouWantToOrder.sortBy(_._2).reverse`

Answer (score 3):

You can just call `wordCounts.sortBy(_._2, false)`. Method *sortBy* from *RDD* takes boolean as the second argument, which tells if the result should be sorted ascending (*true* - default) or descending (*false*).

```
textFile
   .flatMap(_.split(" "))
   .map(word => (word, 1))
   .reduceByKey(_ + _)
   .sortBy(_._2,  false)
```

Comment: Great to hear that :)